# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'signedCookies')

Tags: javascript, next.js, typeerror

I have this error with cookies in my code but I don't think it's a typo.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'signedCookies')

```
// auth.js 
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

export const getServerSideToken = (req) => {
  const { signedCookies = {} } = req

  if (!signedCookies) {
    return {}
  } else if (!signedCookies.token) {
    return {}
  }
  return { user: signedCookies.token }
}

const WINDOW_USER_SCRIPT_VARIABLE = '__USER__'

export const getUserScript = (user) => {
  return `${WINDOW_USER_SCRIPT_VARIABLE} = ${JSON.stringify(user)}`
}

export const loginUser = async (email, password) => {
  const { data } = await axios.post('/api/login', { email, password })
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window[WINDOW_USER_SCRIPT_VARIABLE] = data || {}
  }
}

export const getUserProfile = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get('/api/profile')
  return data
}
```

The error seems to be here and I don't know why

```
> 6 |   const { signedCookies = {} } = req
    |          ^
  7 | 
  8 |   if (!signedCookies) {
  9 |     return {}
```

I use this auth.js file in a _document.js file :

```
//_document.js
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { getServerSideToken, getUserScript } from '../lib/auth'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const props = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    const userData = await getServerSideToken(ctx.req)

    return { ...props, ...userData }
  }

  render() {
    const { user = {} } = this.props

    return (
      <html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: getUserScript(user) }} />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sounds like `ctx.req` is undefined

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, `ctx.req` is always defined inside `_document`'s `getInitialProps`. Are you certain the error comes from that file? Are you using `getServerSideToken` anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when I was on a tutorial video for the custom document page in next.js.

And I was able to avoid the error by using the `req` parameter directly in `getServerSideToken` like below:

```
export const getServerSideToken = req => {
    if (!req) {
        return {};
    } else if (!req.token) {
        return {};
    }
    return { user: req.token }
}
```

This leads an expected result page without error, but I'll post additional answer when I have a more fundamental solution.

I hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, indeed it works now. Thank you